# How to match from the list which keys are mentioned in the order of dictionary

Tags: python

A list and dictionary is below

```
main_list = ["projecttype", "emptype", "Designation"]
sample = {
    "query": {
        "emptype": ["Manager"],
        "Designation": ["Developer"],
        "from": ["0"],
        "q": [""], 
        "projecttype": ["temp"],
        "size": ["4"]
    }
}
```

How to find from the `main_list` which keys are mentioned in the `order` of dictionary. I am using 3.7

Expected out is

`{"emptype":["Manager"], "Designation":["Developer"], "projecttype":["temp"] }`

Comment: `{key: items for key, items in sample["query"].items() if key in main_list}`

Comment: @falsetru probably better the other way around, `{k:sample['query'][k] for k in main_list if k in sample['query']}` if `main_list` is large, although if it's small either way works

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, OP requires to keep the order in which they present in the dict

Comment: If it's large, we can make a set to reduce membership test time:`main_set = set(main_list); {key: items for key, items in sample["query"].items() if key in main_set}`

Comment: @falsetru ah, missed that requirement, although, I am skeptical of it as a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go;

```
 main_list = ["projecttype", "emptype", "Designation"]
sample = {
    "query": {
        "emptype": ["Manager"],
        "Designation": ["Developer"],
        "from": ["0"],
        "q": [""], 
        "projecttype": ["temp"],
        "size": ["4"]
    }
}
dc = {}

for key, value in sample["query"].items():
    for i in range(len(main_list)):
        if key == main_list[i]:
            dc[main_list[i]] = value
print(dc)
```

Comment: But remember on thing, dict objects are not ordered ones, so the order may vary from the order of the list.

Comment: Please leave an upvote also if it helped. Thanks!